# Split and Concat Unique SQL comma separated values in column, and then group by

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I am trying to write a SQL query that helps me find out the unique amount of "Numbers" that show up in a specific column. Example, in a select * query, the column I want can look like this

```
Num_Option
9000
9001
9000,9001,9002
8080
8080,8000,8553
```

I then have another field of "date_available" which is a date/time.

Basically, what want is something where I can group by the "date_available" while combing all the Num_Options on that date, so something like this..

```
Num_Option                        date_available
9000,9001,9002,8080                 10/22/2020
9000,9002,8080,8000,8553            10/23/2020
```

I am struggling to figure this out. I have gotten to the possible point of using a python script and matplotlib instead... but I am hoping there is a SQL way of handling this as well.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots, they are quite different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `regexp_split_to_table()` in a lateral join to turn the csv elements to rows, then `string_agg()` to aggregate by date:

```
select string_agg(x.num, ',') num_option, t.date_available
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.num_option, ',') x(num)
group by date_available
```

Of course, this assumes that you want to avoid duplicate nums on the same data (otherwise, there is not need to split, you can directly aggregate).

Comment: Hmm, I am doing this and getting an error

`SELECT string_agg(x.num, ',') num_option, date_available from team.metric_data
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(num_option, ',') x(num)
group by date_available`


`cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(num_option, ',') x(num)
                                                           ^
1 statement failed.`

Its point at the coma/whitespace before ','

Comment: Actually, looks like this is a hard block for me, think I got it working, but because the data is larger than 65535, its hitting a hard limit. So, might need to get this data in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You may just be able to use `string_agg()`:

```
select date_available, string_agg(num_option, ',')
from t
group by date_available;
```

Comment: He wants unique amount of numbers, so it must be converted to table first

Comment: @astentx . . . That makes sense, but the sample data does not illustrate whether that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to split the strings into multiple rows with something like `split_part('9000,9001,9002',',',1)` etc. (use `UNION ALL` to append the 2nd number etc.), then group them back by availability date with `string_agg`

if you don't want to hardcode `split_part` part there is an answer here on how to dynamically split strings in Redshift, look for it